# Batch file that outputs comma separated string into multi-line text file

Tags: batch-file

I have a batch file that opens cmd.exe to take user input. User input is to be in string format and comma separated. Example: data1,data2,data3

How can I split this string by comma and output to a multi line text file? My code below is only spitting out a text file with data1 but leaves out data2 and data3.

```
@ECHO OFF
SET /P skus=Enter comma separated data (no spaces) or one at a time:

IF "%data%"=="" GOTO Error

for /F "tokens=1,* delims=," %%A in ("%data%") DO (
echo %%A >> data.txt
)

:Error
ECHO You did not enter any data! Good-bye!!
:End
```

Comment: Helps if you use the correct variable names.  Either change your SET /P variable to be **data** or change your IF command and FOR /F command to use the **skus** variable.  Use a FOR command instead of a FOR /F

Comment: Ahh yes...messy use of variable names when changing my code for the Stack Overflow question. Thanks for the heads up.

Comment: Your `for` line says:"put the first item in %%A, and the rest of the line (`*`) in %%B"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@ECHO OFF
SET /P data=Enter comma separated data (no spaces) or one at a time:

IF "%data%"=="" GOTO Error

for %%A in (%data%) DO echo %%A >> data.txt


:Error
ECHO You did not enter any data! Good-bye!!
:End
```

Asks for input
Checks for input but not valid input.
parses the variable.